# How to fix ''(master #) ~ $" on terminal?

Tags: bash, git, terminal

The original terminal is displayed as: `username ~ $`

After I use `git Init`, the command line has changed to: `username (master #) ~ $`

I am using macOS Mojave. I have tried to type `bash`, it will turn into the normal terminal for a while, but if I close the terminal and restart it, it jumps back to `username (master #) ~ $`

I think I might have turned the whole home directory into a repository, how can I change it back?

Comment: That's not a programming question, so probably better suited to e.g. superuser.com. As a new user, always take the [tour] and read [ask] to get an overview of conventions, other sites will have similar guidelines.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+home+directory

Comment: @phd Thank you for providing the right keywords, I have solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_description) of `git init` it will basically set up a repository by creating a (hidden) `.git/` folder.

**TLDR:**
Delete the hidden **git** repository folder `~/.git/`